# Why does my <a> not expand with the dimensions of my <img>?

Tags: html, css

**HTML structure**

```
<div id="header_div">
    <a href="#">
        <img width="250" height="75" src="./images/header_logo.png">
    </a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
:hover{
outline:1px dotted red;/*this line help us to actually see*/
}

#header_div{
-moz-border-radius-topright:8px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft:8px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius:8px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius:8px;
border-top-right-radius:8px;
border-top-left-radius:8px;
border:1px solid #477BA3;
border-bottom:0;
background:#5BA2D9 url('./images/header_bg.png') repeat-x left bottom;
}

#header_div img{
border:0;
padding:5px 10px;
}
```

I used the Google Chrome element-inspector and noted that the `height` is `40px` (of the `<a>`)

Live visual example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9qxfB/)

Comment: I don't see a red outline, only a blue one, in case that matters.

Comment: @MatthewGreen liar, the link couldn't work more perfectly.... However I agree with you, I moved to JSFiddle so it last forever (or at least longer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `<a>` is an inline element. Try some CSS:

```
#header_div {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#header_div a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

`<a>` is an inline element, therefore (with the exception of "with") it does not abide by structural properties such as "height". This is solved by `display: block;`.

Block element occupy as the entire width of their parent by default, but you wanted the `<a>` element to wrap tightly around your image. This is solved by `float: left;`.

Because the `<a>` element is the only object inside `#header`, `#header` collapses when `<a>` floats.  This is solved by `overflow: hidden;`, which is a cheap "[clearfix](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)".

> When a float is contained within a container box that has a visible border or background, that float does not automatically force the container's bottom edge down as the float is made taller. Instead the float is ignored by the container and will hang down out of the container bottom like a flag.
>
> > **Source:** http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html

Comment: I tried that before, but the `<a>` expands to the whole header (giving an unwanted link to 'home' on the whole blue area). and the same thing happens if applied to `<img>`

Comment: it works now :D, do you mind explaining the magic behind your code? I am curious about what exactly happened

Comment: I've edited my answer to include an explanation. Hope it helps!

Comment: good explanation, about the collapse thing, I prefer to put a div at the end with the class `.clear{clear:both;font-size:0;line-height:0;}`

Comment: This is extra unnecessary markup, goes against current web standards, and is a semantic no-no. Read [this](http://css-tricks.com/semantic-animation/) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701015/css-clearing-floats). But sure... it'll work.

Comment: for me it's a yes-yes, I have the fear other solutions (such as your `overflow:hidden;`) might not work on all browsers and their older versions.

Comment: I used `overflow: hidden;` to keep the solution simple, but I usually use [clearfix](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/). In any case, I'm glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `display:block;` to #header_div img.  It worked for me.

Comment: that code alone would expand somehow the link to the whole header. I tried that with  `#header_div img` and  `#header_div a` and it creates this unwanted effect